# Django djoser 401/400 for creating users

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js, djoser

I deployed a nuxt app to heroku and when I am running it locally, the app is working fine. On the other hand in production the login / register is not working it is always says 400 bad request (there is no explaination why it is a bad request) or 401 unauthorized.

When I am running the up locally, I am pointing to the backend api and it is working fine.

But when it is run in heroku, I get the errors (400 and sometimes 401), oddly it's worked like there random times from different devices but when I logged out and retry create a user errors.

I did not change the code.

I am not sure the problem is with my code or heroku or maybe Pythonanywhere which I am using to host my backend.

It is my first time deploy python DRF as backend and nuxt as front.
My backend is in python DRF.

- My front-end nuxt repo [nuxt repo](https://github.com/1shaked/nuxt-todo)
- My [DRF code backend repo](https://github.com/1shaked/todo).

In the nuxt app you can see register component with function onSubmit which should register the user and then log him in.

And DRF there is an app name `users_auth` which has the user model as `CustomUser` and the Todo model.

`nuxt.config.js` points to the same place locally and in production.

Comment: Hi ! have you found the solution?

Comment: No, instead I used rest_auth and allauth and it is working.